# How to create a symlink to PyPy

Tags: command-line, symlink, pypy

The PyPy docs mention creating a symlink to allow pypy to be used globally, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it.

I currently have this command: `mklink \pypy C:\pypy`

However, it keeps coming up with an error saying `Access is denied.`. Any idea as to how I could fix this and get it working? Despite it being brought up in the PyPy docs, there's no mention of how to actually do it.

PyPy itself is contained in `C:\pypy`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the file paths, I am actually assuming that  you are working on `Windows`.

The advice you actually read ([here](http://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/getting-started.html#installing-pypy)) applies to `Linux`. That's why you can not do that in `Windows`.

Also please not that `\pypy` is not a valid option for the `windows` `mklink` program.

Comment: Is there any way that it can be done, then? Maybe adding it to environment variables or something?

Comment: @dantdj why would you like to do that? It is already universally available on windows. Do you mean that you want it to be the default python implementation that handles python files in windows?

Comment: My install didn't let me type `pypy script.py` in commmand line and let it run. But I added it to my path and now I can, so no worries.

Comment: @dantdj if that answer helped you, please mark it as accepted so that future readers can see that it solved your problem.

Comment: The link 404's - please add some content from the linked page for reference.

Answer (score 0):

For linux, download the tar.bz2 file from https://www.pypy.org/download.html, unpack it and then:

```
sudo ln -s /path/to/pypy/download/folder /usr/local/bin/pypy
```